# Three finger swipe not working with xswipe

Tags: dell, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I installed xSwipe per [instructions](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe) on my Dell XPS 13 (9343, early 2015) with Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 .

Launching it with `$ perl ~/xSwipe-master/xSwipe.pl` works fine, but **it doesn't detect three-finger touches**.
That's weird, since my [synaptics capabilities](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Using_xinput_to_determine_touchpad_capabilities) are :

```
Synaptics Capabilities (325):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

so three-finger touches should be detected.

Is it because xSwipe requires a fall-back to older synaptic drivers?

Answer (score 0):

xSwipe is limited, it focuses on swiping, vertical or horizontal, and on multi-finger clicks. There is no support for pinching, rotating or tapping, and there are no application specific gestures.

In order for it to work you need to install libx11-guitest-perl

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install libx11-guitest-perl
```

If you already have a synaptics conf file then open it up and check your trackpad section for the line:

```
Option "SHMConfig" "on"
```

[Source & More info](https://www.elementarynow.com/multitouch-trackpads-luna/)

Comment: `libx11-guitest-perl` is already installed and the synaptics conf file is properly configured, per the tutorial.